# Error in Angular 6 : No component factory found for PostJobComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, mean-stack, typescript2.0, ngx-admin

I am creating a web app using MEAN stack framework and the Angular version is 6. There I am using the ngx-admin template. I created a component called 'postJob' in pages folder.

ex: src->app->pages->post-job.

I added newly created post job component into entryComponents in pages module as well.

pages. module.ts

```
const PAGES_COMPONENTS = [
  PagesComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    DashboardModule,

    MiscellaneousModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...PAGES_COMPONENTS,
    PostJobComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [PostJobComponent]
})
export class PagesModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector){
    console.log("This is pages module");
    const customPostJob= createCustomElement(PostJobComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('post-job',customPostJob);
  }
  ngDoBootstrap(){}
}
```

But it gives following error when debugging the application.

**No component factory found for PostJobComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?**

Here is the structure of my project directories.

[image: The Structure of the project directories]

I tried several solutions in the internet related to my problem. But it did not work. Can anyone help me to understand my mistake?

Comment: show the structure of your project directories

Comment: I edited the question by adding the structure of my project directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have more than 1 module

put this component in the root module or import that module to the appModule